# automatically try different initial values in optim

Tags: r, optimization, error-handling

I use `optim(.)` to try to find the best fitting parameters for some function `fn(dat, par, out=FALSE)` where `par` must be a vector of two elements and `out` determines the output format. I use

```
optim(par=c(1,1), fn, dat=dat)
```

to identify the best-fitting values of `par`. Depending on the data in `dat`, this either works ot throws an error that

```
function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters
```

which I understand requires different starting values for `optim(.)`. My problem is that I apply the function to many data sets in parallel and wonder whether I indeed need to try different values by hand or whether there is some way of automatizing this along the lines of

```
if no error then great
if error try par=c(0.5,1)
if no error then great
if error try par=c(0.5,0.5)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run a grid search before you start and discard `NA` parameters. Here is an example.

A test function:

```
fn <- function(x) {
    if (x[1] < 0)
        NA
    else
        prod(x)
}
```

Now run a grid search.

```
library("NMOF")    
res <- gridSearch(fn,
                  npar = 2,   ## length of x
                  lower = -1, ## lower bound for x
                  upper = 3,  ## upper bound for x                
                  n = 5)      ## number of levels per element in x
## 2 variables with 5, 5 levels: 25 function evaluations required.
```

The function shows you all the parameter combinations it tried.

```
res$levels
## [[1]]
## [1] -1 -1
## 
## [[2]]
## [1]  0 -1
## 
## [[3]]
## [1]  1 -1
##
##  ....
```

And it provides the objective function values associated with these combinations.

```
res$values
##  [1] NA  0 -1 -2 -3 NA  0  0  0  0 NA  0  1  2  3
## [16] NA  0  2  4  6 NA  0  3  6  9

## => many objective functions values are NA
```

The best (none-`NA`) solution:

```
res$minlevels 
## [1]  3 -1

## => your starting value for optim:
##
##    optim(gridSearch(fn, npar = 2,
##                     lower = -1, upper = 3, n = 5)$minlevels,
##          fn, dat = dat)
```

Of course, this won't give you a guarantee that at least one none-`NA`vector is found, but the chances may improve.